# How to do server-side rendering in React/redux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am new to react/redux I little confused with server side rending in react/redux,
Yes i saw some example on the internet but when i tried with mock api with external server , server side rendering is not working .

cat.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as mockApi from '../Actions/mockActions';
class Cat extends React.Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.getMockApi();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Hello Dude
                {this.props.mock.data.map((data,i) => {
                    return <li key={i}>{data.email}</li>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
       mock:state.mock
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getMockApi:() => dispatch(mockApi.getMockData())
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Cat);
```

mockActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as types from './actionTypes';

export function getMockData() {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
            dispatch(setThisData(response.data))
        })
    }
}

export function setThisData(data) {

    return {
        type:types.MOCK_API,
        payload:data
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import Cat from './components/cat'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './Store/configureStore';
import { createStore ,applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import counterApp from './Reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';







if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    // Grab the state from a global variable injected into the server-generated HTML
    const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__

// Allow the passed state to be garbage-collected
    delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
    const store = createStore(counterApp, preloadedState, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)))


    render(
        <Provider store={store} >
            <Cat/>
        </Provider>
        ,
        document.getElementById('app')
    )



}
```

devServer.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import webpackHotMidleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import counterApp from '../../src/client/ReduxServer/Reducers';
import App from '../../src/client/ReduxServer/components/cat';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'


import webpackConfig from '../../webpack.config.dev';


let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'))


const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    hot: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true
}));

app.use(webpackHotMidleware(compiler));


// app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../index.html'))
// });


//Redux Start
app.use(handleRender);

function handleRender(req,res) {
   const store = createStore(counterApp);

   const html = renderToString(
       <Provider store={store} >
           <App/>
       </Provider>
   )
    const preloadedState = store.getState();
    // Send the rendered page back to the client
    res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
}
function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
    console.log(preloadedState)
    return `
            <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div id="app">${html}</div>
          <script>
           window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
        </script>

      <script src="bundle.js"></script>

      </body>
  </html>
        `
}







//Redux Ends








app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening')
});
```

Right now this will only server render the hello dude but not the mock Api call data .I know that missed to fetch the data  from server side but the point is what will i do If ihave to render a two components and that component has 5 api reuqest ,And how to fecth the correct api Request

Right Now My client Side Prefecthed state will look like this

```
 window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = {"mock":{"data":[]}}
```

Comment: Why don't you try with http://mern.io/. It has inbuild server side rendering.

Comment: I want to learn these things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, to make this clear, you've created the code to handle server rendering. However, it doesn't load the data that is supposed to be fetched right?

You've done the first step, great! The next step is to load the actual dynamic data to the store. Let's look at this code here

```js
function handleRender(req,res) {
   const store = createStore(counterApp);

   const html = renderToString(
       <Provider store={store} >
           <App/>
       </Provider>
   )
    const preloadedState = store.getState();
    // Send the rendered page back to the client
    res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
}
```

What happened is that you created a store. The store is used to render the html into a string. Then you get the store state and put it into preloadedState.

This is great accept that renderToString will **not** call *this.props.getMockApi();* as you would expect.

Instead, you have to fetch the state *before* you call renderToString();

In this case, what you could do is as following. (Note that this is just an example, you probably want to use something more general in production, especially if you use something like react-router.)

```js
import * as mockApi from '../Actions/mockActions';

function handleRender(req, res) {
  const store = createStore(counterApp);

  store.dispatch(mockApi.getMockData())
  // And since you used redux-thunk, it should return a promise
  .then(() => {
    const html = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
      </Provider>
    )
    const preloadedState = store.getState();
    // Send the rendered page back to the client
    res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
  });
}
```

Simple isn't it? ;D, nah just joking. This is one part of react where there's not really an exact solution to the problem yet.

Personally, if I had the choice to go back in time, I'd tell myself to learn other stuff other than server rendering. There are other techniques such as code splitting, lazy loading, etc that I could've used instead. With server rendering, if the javascript arrives long after the user has seen the initial page, they might get frustrated by other things that require js. For example in my case, some links are not working, some buttons don't do anything, etc.

I'm not saying that server rendering is not good. It's an interesting technique, just that there are other techniques that are more beneficial to learn first (Oh, and server rendering basically locks you to use nodejs for your backend). Good luck to you :)

Comment: Great It works ,But how to do it if I am using react router ?

Comment: What i would do is basically: Create a static function on each components. This function will hold all the data call. On your handleRender(), use react-router's [match](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md) to find the list of components that are going to be rendered. After that, call the static function that you created before

Comment: Well I am a beginner Could you pls answer here ...  [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125549/what-is-the-proper-way-to-do-server-side-rendering-with-react-redux-react-route)

Comment: There are a lot of articles that can explain those better than i could. For example, [https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/redux-server-rendering-react-router-universal-web-app](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/redux-server-rendering-react-router-universal-web-app)

Comment: It doesn't work, because action's function returns promise, not dispatch!

Comment: @DarynK. Use redux-thunk for that

Comment: If you have any components that modify the state via dispatching actions on-load, other components that depend on those changes won't receive them unless you render a second time through. This is because `connect` normally re-renders components on state changes, but does not do this when rendering server-side on a single-pass.